# How to auto focus a second text input after confirming the first in react native

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a react native app with a simple sign-in form containing two textInputs: one for username and the other for password. The username textInput has the property autoFocus={'true'}. After submit(return key on virtual keyboard) the second textInput for password should autofocus. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: use BecomeFirstResponder when first textField's Return button pressed

Answer (score 3):

You'll need a function on your parent component that will focus the password field:

```
function focusPassword() {
    this.refs.password.focus();
}
```

Then define the `onSubmitEditing` property on the first TextInput. This will be called when the user hits enter (or "next" if you use  `returnKeyType='next'`)

```
<TextInput ref='username' onSubmitEditing=this.focusPassword />
<TextInput ref='password' />
```

Answer (score -3):

Make sure both textfield have delegate connected to you VC.
and use the textfield delegate method for the return button

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

{

```
if (textField == self.firstTextField)
{
    [self.secondTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}

else [textField resignFirstResponder];

return NO;
```

}

Comment: I think OP is looking for react-native code, not objc